# sftp: No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication

Tags: c#, linux

i am using below code and return error as `No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`.  Can some one give an idea

`ConnectionInfo conInfo = new ConnectionInfo("136.XX.xx.xx", 22, "1user", keybAuth);`

my code:-

```
    using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(conInfo))
    {
        sftp.Connect();

        // Get linux server memory informatioin

      
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to it from the command line?

Comment: yes.. ican able to connect using putty from my pc

Comment: Use sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare headers in first request between working and non working app.  Then make c# request headers look like working putty.  The default headers in c# are different from putty.